# jQuery keyword cannot recognize error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.6.1 and want to use JqGrid (a grid table plugin for JQuery). However when I use it, I get the following error in Firebug:

```
jQuery("#confTable").jqGrid is not a function
```

I changed it to this:

```
$("#confTable").jqGrid is not a function
```

I tried using `jQuery.noConflict();` before jqGrid code but still get the same error?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things:

1. Quentin sounds right. It might not be loaded, check the path and filename are correct (caps is important (usuaLlY))
2. noConflict() is a bugger to use. It's only neccessary if you have 2 javascript libraries, like jquery and mootools. You have to use it after both libraries are loaded but before (most) plugins. This is because many plugin writters are lazy and use $ where they should use jQuery.

noConflict is a huge pain. I can only get it to work after an hour of tinkering, good luck.

Answer (score 3):

This indicates that you have not loaded the plugin script (at least at the time you try to use it).